# How to terminate my app when it was initially launched by system into background

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Hi I'm building an app that uses background location updates. The app uses region monitoring so it will be launched by the system into background automatically when user leaves a region that the app previously registered to monitor even when the app is not running (with 'always' location permission).

The question is, after my app finishes its task in the background and registers for a new region to monitor, it will keep running in the background (suppose that user does not use significant resources in other app that will cause my app to terminate to save memory and stuff). Since my app isn't really do anything now in the background, it will not consume a lot of power, but it will show up in the battery page with a very long background usage time which can be terrifying to the user.

Is there a way to programmatically terminate my app now to stop it from running in the background? (This is OK because the app has registered for a new region to monitor and will later be brought up again if user leaves)

Comment: Your app won't be *running* in the background. It will be *suspended* and able to run in the background. It can actually use more power to relaunch an app than to leave it suspended. Let iOS manage resources by jettisoning your app as required.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi I don't think you understand my question here. So the app can be launched in two ways: 1. By the user (normal stuff) 2. By the system (This will result in my app being launched directly into background, i.e. my app was terminated long before and now it is launched to handle events). The question here is: when will the system terminate my background app? Or is there a way for me to terminate my background app when I'm finished

Comment: The system will terminate your app when it needs to.  You will only run in the background for a few seconds at most and then it will be suspended

Comment: @Paulw11 After some testing I think you are right. Is there any documentation from Apple that defines what happens to apps that are launched directly into background?

Comment: It isn't about how they are launched. It is about the [app lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle). If your app is not actively executing in the foreground or the background then it is suspended. When it is suspended it is eligible to be terminated if iOS needs memory.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks! I think I understand now